# Unexpected behavior of Arduino

Tags: memory, arduino, microcontroller, gsm, spi

Currently I am working on Arduino with some ICs i.e. ADC IC with SPI interface, Isolators ,16x2 LCD and GSM/GPRS module. Everything is working fine if I deal separately with each IC or module whatever.  But if integrated all device and programming then Arduino behave unexpected it stops working and after some time it starts itself very slowly from void main setup because I have print to LCD so I notify that.
Now after a while it will start working properly and will repeat this procedure again and again. I am using a one second interrupt and do only increment in a global variable. As I am checking free RAM memory at many instant but it never goes below 900 bytes and used flash memory is around 15kb then what’s going wrong men, I am bitterly confused.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code, you should probably paste it here

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, it is actually a bit hard to say anything without looking at the code. My suggestion is that make sure you have an initialization sequence for all the peripherals you have got on your circuit. 
Also, analyze your code to check all your global variables are set and reset properly.